# Toggle menu don't open on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I am faced with the following problem. I have a menu that doesn't open at all on mobile devices.. and on tablets either.. I can't figure it out.. what could it be. Can you help me?

HTML code

```
<div class="aside">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="pages/home.php">
          <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" with="100px" height="100px">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-toggler">
        <span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="index.php?page=home" class="<?php echo ($page === 'home') ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=about" class="<?php echo ($page === 'about') ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> About</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=portfolio" class="<?php echo ($page === 'portfolio') ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=contact" class="<?php echo ($page === 'contact') ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript code

```
      const navTogglerBtn = document.querySelector(".nav-toggler"),
            aside = document.querySelector(".aside");
            navTogglerBtn.addEventListener("click", () => 
            {
                asideSectionTogglerBtn();
            })
            function asideSectionTogglerBtn()
            {
                aside.classList.toggle("open");
                navTogglerBtn.classList.toggle("open");
                for(let i=0; i<totalSection; i++ )
                {
                    allSection[i].classList.toggle("open");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

include meta tag in head section go through this link know more about responsive navigation bar ,by creating responsive navigation bar u can open in any devices the window will resize according to device size.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).